# Setter for field is removed by type projection

Tags: generics, kotlin, erasure

I have the following SSCCE:

```
class Foo(val bars: Map<Int, Bar<*>>) {

    fun <Baz> qux(baz: Baz) {
        val bar2 = bars[2]!!
        bar2.bazes += baz
    }

    interface Bar<Baz> {
        var bazes: MutableList<Baz>
    }
}
```

This seems fine to me, but the compiler complains that:

```
Error:(5, 9) Kotlin: Setter for 'bazes' is removed by type projection
```

I have no idea what this even means, much less how to correct it. What's going on here and how do I get around it?

Comment: `bars[2]!!` is retrieving a `Bar<*>`, which makes `bar.bazes` a `MutableList<*>`, so you shouldn't be able to add/set that list at all since you do not know the actual type parameter. Remember that the functions' generic type parameter is unrelated and may be anything. As to why the error message is so cryptic, no idea...but that definitely shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple little issues. Temporarily using `bars[2]!! as Bar<Baz>`,

```
w: (4, 20): Unchecked cast: Foo.Bar<Any?> to Foo.Bar<Baz>
e: (5, 20): Assignment operators ambiguity: 
public operator fun <T> Collection<Baz>.plus(element: Baz): List<Baz> defined in kotlin.collections
@InlineOnly public operator inline fun <T> MutableCollection<in Baz>.plusAssign(element: Baz): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
```

Kotlin doesn't know whether to handle it as `bar2.bazes = bar2.bazes.plus(baz)` or `bar2.bazes.plusAssign(baz)`. If you change it to `var2.bazes.add(baz)` or `val bazes` the ambiguity goes away.

Fixing that and removing the unsafe cast brings up

```
e: (5, 20): Out-projected type 'MutableList<out Any?>' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun add(element: E): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections.MutableList'
```

the question of what can safely be done with the type projection. It gets treated like `out Any?`, so you can read from the list, but `in Nothing`, which means you can't add anything to the list.

It's unclear from this example why you're using `*`. If it doesn't cause any other issues, perhaps you could lift out the `<Baz>` parameter, e.g.

```kotlin
class Foo<Baz>(val bars: Map<Int, Bar<Baz>>)
```

Answer (score 2):

**The issue:** Your `bars` property is using "star projection", which, put simply, just means: "I don't know the generic type of `Bar`". This in turn leads to a problem: You'll only be able to *get* something from the `MutableList`, *adding* is prohibited (Thus the error message: No **Setter** for `bazes`!).

**A possible solution:**

```
 class Foo<in Baz>(private val bars: Map<Int, Bar<in Baz>>) {

    fun qux(baz: Baz) {
        val bar2 = bars[2]!!
        bar2.bazes.add(baz)
    }

    interface Bar<Baz> {
        var bazes: MutableList<Baz>
    }
}
```

What I changed here, is that I made `Foo` typed with `in Baz`, which means `Foo` is made *contravariant* in its type parameter, thus `Baz`s can only be consumed. The same type is then used for the input parameter `bars`. As a result, you're now able to *add* values into `bars.bazes`, because the associated `MutableList` is said to be a "Consumer" of `Bar`s.

btw: Using `Baz` as a name for the generic type isn't [recommended](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) - You should rather use `T` which is more obvious to be a generic type.

I know, it's a complex topic and I really advise to consult the good [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) as a further step :)

**The plusAssign issue**

The usage of `+=` (`plusAssign` operator) on the other hand is a bit weird:
The compiler complains not to be able to choose the correct operator:

> Assignment operators ambiguity:
>   public operator fun  Collection.plus(element: Any?): List >defined in kotlin.collections
>
> @InlineOnly public operator inline fun 
>   MutableCollection.plusAssign(element: Baz): Unit 
>   defined in kotlin.collections

I tried to explicitly cast `bazes` to `MutableList` which in fact solves the issue. The compiler then complains about an **unecessary** cast though. I don't know how to handle this properly to be honest except using `add` instead ;-)

Comment: As I mentioned, using the declaration `val bazes` instead of `var bazes`, there is no ambiguity and the compiler always resolves to `.plusAssign()`.

Comment: Then you should rather use add imho

Comment: I did. "If you change it to `var2.bazes.add(baz)` or `val bazes` the ambiguity goes away."