Setter for 'value' is removed by type projection - Kotlin
The Problem

Trying to set a wildcard variable to a value, it fails with the error "Setter for  is removed by type projection".  This error occurs at the following line:
property.value = ref.value

See below for more context.
Source code

ModuleProperty.kt
class ModuleProperty<T>(val name: String, @JsonProperty("value") var value: T) :
    ReadWriteProperty<Module, T>, Serializable {
        
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Module, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return value
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Module, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        this.value = value
    }
}

UI.kt (not everything)
selectedModule!!.properties.forEach { property ->
    val element = ElementRegistry.getElement(property)
    val value = property.value!!
    
    val ref = atomic(value)
    element?.draw(ref, property)
    if (value != ref.value) {
        property.value = ref.value
    }
}

ElementRegistry.kt
object ElementRegistry {

    private val elements = mapOf<KClass<*>, UIElement<*>>(
        Boolean::class to BooleanElement(),
        Int::class to IntElement(),
    )

    fun getElement(property: ModuleProperty<*>): UIElement<*>? {
        return elements[property.value!!::class]
    }
    
}

PS: The implementations of UIElement don't matter in this case
I tried using reflections, however that did not work for advanced types.
I am expecting to simply set property.value to ref.value.

Can you please [edit] the question and make the code a [mcve]?

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789446/setter-for-field-is-removed-by-type-projection
